# kivy: How to change Switch default from ON/OFF to OPEN/CLOSE or to YES/NO?

Tags: kivy

To be more clearly, I want the text of the Switch changed from `On/Off` to `Open/Close` or `Yes/No`.  I did not find out how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hack this by changing the background image of the right rectangle in the Switch.
You can make an icon that is 83x32 pixels like the widget.
I Made a very ugly example on [sumo](https://www.sumopaint.com) an online photoeditor:
[image]
Then I saved it as `images/icon.jpg`
If you want to change the slider too, its 43x32 pixels.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch


class MyGui(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyGui,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.switch = Switch()

        self.switch.canvas.children[2].source = "images/icon.jpg" # The slider is the last element, so in that case -> children[-1].source

        self.add_widget(self.switch)



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyGui()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

If you want to do this in kv language, you could do like this:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<MyGui>:
    Switch:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                source: 'switch.jpg'        # make or download your background jpg
                size: sp(83), sp(32)
                pos: int(self.center_x - sp(41)), int(self.center_y - sp(16))
            Rectangle:
                source: 'switch_slider.jpg' # make or download your slider jpg
                size: sp(43), sp(32)
                pos: int(self.center_x - sp(41) + self.active_norm_pos * sp(41)), int(self.center_y - sp(16))
""")

class MyGui(Widget):
    pass
```

Comment: How would you express that property `canvas.children[2].source` in the kv-language?

Comment: @EL2PHATEN Thanks!

Comment: @Nearoo, your wellcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The switch text is sadly not a text but an image. You can find the kv file [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/79aeb700ebba0a884ba83b47abe59678d6c1a351/kivy/data/style.kv#L465). You should be able to provide a different theme (see [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Theming-Kivy)) or you can override the class and implement your own rendering (which then displays OPEN/CLOSE) instead of the ON/OFF.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to change its whole appearance, you can [patch the `style.kv`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4558) and use a little bit of canvas instructions to create a widget of your taste. ^.^

(and it's a lot more flexible than creating image for each different switch, if you don't want to change its color)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Custom@Switch>:
    values: ['OFF', 'ON']
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.2, 0.709, 0.898, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: [sp(41.5), sp(20)]
            pos: [self.center_x - sp(41.5), self.center_y - sp(10)]
        Color:
            rgb: 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: [sp(41.5), sp(20)]
            pos: [self.center_x, self.center_y - sp(10)]
    Label:
        text: '[b]{}[/b]'.format(root.values[0])
        markup: True
        font_size: 13
        pos: [root.center_x - sp(70), root.center_y - sp(50)]
    Label:
        color: 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1
        text: '[b]{}[/b]'.format(root.values[1])
        markup: True
        font_size: 13
        pos: [root.center_x - sp(30), root.center_y - sp(50)]

<Test>:
    Custom:
    Switch:
    Custom:
        values: ['Yes', 'No']
''')
class Test(BoxLayout): pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Comment: This is cool, but the labels you generate appear in front of the switch... any way to fix this?

Comment: @Nearoo using the latest kivy version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using @el3in's solution make sure to clarify `canvas.after` instead of `canvas` otherwise the original switch image stays on top ;)