# Change Switch colour in python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible to change the colour of a kivy `Switch` widget?

I know that for a `Button` widget you set eg `background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1`.

So I tried setting `background_color` to change the colour of my `Switch`. **Strangely, it doesn't change the colour of my `Switch` but **there is no error message** either**.

Thanks!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv = '''
<RedSwitch>:
size_hint: None, None
size: 100, 100
    
Switch:
    id: new_switch  
    background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    pos: 50, 50
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 50
    active: False   
    on_active: switch_callback() 
    
'''

class RedSwitch(FloatLayout):
        
    def switch_callback(self):
        pass       
        
class SwitchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return RedSwitch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SwitchApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: [kivy: How to change Switch default from ON/OFF to OPEN/CLOSE or to YES/NO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082122/kivy-how-to-change-switch-default-from-on-off-to-open-close-or-to-yes-no)

```
kv = '''
<RedSwitch>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100

    Switch:
        id: new_switch  
        active: False   
        on_active: root.switch_callback()

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: sp(41.5), sp(20)
                pos: self.center_x - sp(40.0), self.center_y - sp(10)
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: sp(41.0), sp(20)
                pos: self.center_x, self.center_y - sp(10)
        Label:
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            text: 'ON'
            bold: True
            font_size: 13
            pos: self.parent.center_x - sp(70), self.parent.center_y - sp(50)                
        Label:
            color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            text: 'OFF'
            bold: True
            font_size: 13
            pos: self.parent.center_x - sp(30), self.parent.center_y - sp(50)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kivymd

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv = '''
<RedSwitch>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
        
    MDSwitch:
        id: new_switch  
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        pos: 50, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 50
        active: False 
        
        track_color_active : "red"
        thumb_color_active : "red"
        track_color_inactive : "blue"
        thumb_color_inactive : "blue"

        on_active: root.switch_callback() 
        
'''

class RedSwitch(FloatLayout):
        
    def switch_callback(self):
        pass       
        
class SwitchApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return RedSwitch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SwitchApp().run()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).